# How did servants refer to their aristocratic masters in 16th century Spain?

Tags: historia

How would they say "my master?" Obviously "mi señor" but anything else? I don't mean how they would address their employer but specifically what words they would use in talking about him. Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: Maybe you could take as reference how Sancho Panza refers to his master Don Quixote in [the Spanish original](http://bdh-rd.bne.es/viewer.vm?id=0000042946) from very early 17th century.

Comment: I appreciate that. I did have a look through Don Quixote but wasn't able to find Sancho referring to his master. It's a huge work so I'll try again.

Comment: In a different context, master would mean "mi amo", slaves saying that

Answer (score 4):

If we can trust Sancho to be an example of correct etiquette, we could conclude that he addressed his master as "vuestra merced" (also, "vuesa merced"):

"Sancho: ¿Qué gigantes?

Quijote: Aquellos que allí ves, de los brazos largos, que los suelen tener algunos de casi dos leguas.

Sancho: Mire **vuestra merced** que aquellos que allí se parecen no son gigantes, sino molinos de viento, y lo que en ellos parecen brazos son las aspas, que, volteadas del viento, hacen andar la piedra del molino."

"Sancho: ¡Válame Dios! ¿No le dije yo a **vuestra merced** que mirase bien lo que hacía, que no eran sino molinos de viento, y no lo podía ignorar sino quien llevase otros tales en la cabeza?

Quijote: Calla, amigo Sancho, que las cosas de la guerra más que otras están sujetas a continua mudanza; cuanto más, que yo pienso, y es así verdad, que aquel sabio Frestón que me robó el aposento y los libros ha vuelto estos gigantes en molinos, por quitarme la gloria de su vencimiento: tal es la enemistad que me tiene; mas al cabo han de poder poco sus malas artes contra la bondad de mi espada."

When Sancho spoke of Don Quijote in the latter's absence, he referred to him as both "my master" (mi amo) and "my lord" (mi señor):

"Bien puede ser todo eso; y agora quiero creer lo que **mi amo** cuenta [de la cueva de Montesinos]; y [en cuanto a mi encanto de Dulcinea] todo debió de ser al revés, como vuesa merced, señora mía, dice, porque de mi ruin ingenio no se puede ni debe presumir que fabricase en un instante tan agudo embuste [. . .]; yo fingí aquello por escaparme de las riñas de **mi señor** don Quijote, y no con intención de ofenderle; y si ha salido al revés, Dios está en el cielo, que juzga los corazones. [. . .] Verdad sea que la que yo vi fue una labradora, y por labradora la tuve, y por tal labradora la juzgué; y si aquélla era Dulcinea, no ha de estar a mi cuenta, ni ha de correr por mí, o sobre ello, morena. No, sino ándense a cada triquete conmigo a dime y direte, “Sancho lo dijo, Sancho lo hizo, Sancho tornó y Sancho volvió”, como si Sancho fuese algún quienquiera, y no fuese el mismo Sancho Panza, el que anda ya en libros por ese mundo adelante [. . .]; así, que no hay para qué nadie se tome conmigo, y pues que tengo buena fama, y, según oí decir a **mi señor**, que más vale el buen nombre que las muchas riquezas, encájenme ese gobierno, y verán maravillas; que quien ha sido buen escudero será buen gobernador."

Answer (score 3):

Another form, **mi dueño**:

> —Vuestra merced sí que es escudero fiel y legal, moliente y corriente, magnífico y grande, como lo muestra este banquete, que si no ha venido aquí por arte de encantamento, parécelo a lo menos, y no como yo, mezquino y malaventurado, que sólo traigo en mis alforjas un poco de queso tan duro, que pueden descalabrar con ello a un gigante; a quien hacen compañía cuatro docenas de algarrobas y otras tantas de avellanas y nueces, mercedes a la estrecheza de **mi dueño**, (...)

Fuente: *Don Quijote de la Mancha*, capítulo XIII, *Donde se prosigue la aventura del Caballero del Bosque, con el discreto, nuevo y suave coloquio que pasó entre los dos escuderos*.

---

**Mi señor** y **mi amo**, in the same sentence:

> —¿Es posible que haya en el mundo personas que se atrevan a decir y a jurar que este mi señor es loco? Digan vuestras mercedes, señores pastores: ¿hay cura de aldea, por discreto y por estudiante que sea, que pueda decir lo que mi amo ha dicho, ni hay caballero andante, por más fama que tenga de valiente, que pueda ofrecer lo que mi amo aquí ha ofrecido?

Fuente: *Don Quijote de la Mancha*, Segunda parte, capítulo LVIII: *Que trata de cómo menudearon sobre don Quijote aventuras tantas, que no se daban vagar unas a otras*.